Time Average of a function of adjacent datapoints in a linear dynamical system
Suppose we are given a linear dynamical system
$$
x_t = Ax_{t - 1} + \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)
$$
where $A$ is orthogonal, $x_t \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ is a normal distribution. Also, let $f$ be an arbitrary well-behaved function (say continuous) on $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$. Does the time average
$$
\lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}T \sum_{t = 0}^{T - 1} f(x_t, x_{t + 1})
$$
exist, and if so, under which conditions on $f, A$?
I believe this relates to ergodicity in some way, but don't know how to start...

Is $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ a multivariate random distribution, while $\sigma^2$ is the covariance matrix?

Yes, thanks for the catch :)
